# AWS SDK Unable to find a region via the region provider chain from docker container

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker

I am running a docker container that will point to a mock aws environment localstack on my machine, I am getting the error

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
```

But when I am setting the environment variable un my docker run command.

```
docker run -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-1 -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AXXXXXXXXXXXXE  -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wXXXXXXXXXXXXY --network host -it --name sample-publisher -p 1338:1338 --rm sample-publisher:latest
```

This works for the access and secret access key because if i only provide region to my KMS client in my code i have no issues, I don't want to provide region though I want it to pick up for the env var like the access keys.

Answer (score -1):

`AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-1` is an incorrect region, try `us-west-2`

Comment: You are incorrect, us-west-1 is a correct region https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/tag-policies-regions.html